# Table or Matrix visual is blank in power Bi desktop even though the data is there

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

[image]Table or Matrix visual is showing as blank in power Bi desktop even though the data is there.

Please refer to the attached screenshot. There is no blank value in data and i have checked show item with no data as well but still its not showing the data. When i publish this report is power bi service data is showing for this matrix visualisation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use Peformance Analyzer to get the DAX queries and use DAX Studio to investigate what Filters are getting applied.

Comment: @AntrikshSharma i tried your suggestion. the DAX query is not yet applied. the process is still running. I believe due to this the visualization is not showing the data. please refer to the screenshot attached

Comment: Are you saying that the performance analyzer pane shows execution for indefinite time? It keeps on running and doesn't stop? I also see 8 seconds spent on visual display but there is no DAX Query event in the first execution? Looks like a complex measure that materialzes large data caches but returns absolutely nothing. Can you post sample file on Google Drive and share link I had like to investigate.

Comment: @AntrikshSharma its simple data set with only few rows and two colums. Please refer to the screenshot